# Python Multithread socket server can't receive msg from 2 users

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, python-sockets

does annyone know how i fix this problem? Or does annyone see an error in my code?

So i'm trying to set up a basic localhost socket server. So i can send data between my computer and raspberry pi's. I just want for now a basic chat program so i can later try and add some more code to my server so it responds on some messages.

I got a basic server, and a client, they can connect to each other but the client can't send messages. And also when i connect another client, i can't send messages and i don't know why.

2 days ago, i had almost the same code (was stupid and didn't save the last part and now its all gone...) But then i had the problem that the second client coudn't send messages.

( btw just so you know, i'm quite new to python and programming but i want to get in to it. So my code might be full of strange stings, etc. I also have some unnecersary variables, but when this is finnished i'm gonna clean this mess up)

Can anyone help me?

my code (full code):

```
import threading
import time
import socket
import sys

NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 2
JOB_NUMBER = [1, 2]
thread_list = []

all_connections = []
all_addresses = []

ip = "localhost"
port = 6969
number_of_connections = 5

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


def receive_msg():
    while True:
        msg = clientsocket.recv(1024)
        print(msg.decode("utf-8"))


def accept_connections():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        s.listen()
        clientsocket, address = s.accept()
        print(f"[Server] New connection with {address}")




# MAIN CODE BEGINNING

t1 = threading.Thread(target = receive_msg, name = "thread_recv_msg", args=())
#t2 = threading.Thread(target = accept_connections, name = "accept_connections", args=())




s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((ip, port))
print("[Server] Server online...")
s.listen(number_of_connections)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"[Server] New connection with {address}")

#create_socket()
time.sleep(1)
t1.start()
#t2.start()

# MAIN CODE END
```

My client code:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

#####################

Connecting = True

while Connecting == True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("localhost", 6969))
    Connecting = False

if Connecting == False:
    print("Verbonden met server!") # dutch for: connected with server!

    while True: 
        msg = input("New message: ")
        time.sleep(1)
        s.sendall(bytes(msg, "utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your **server** code :

- a main loop that accepts new connections
- a new thread per client to receive messages

It works for multiple clients now, I let you have a look :

```
import threading
import time
import socket
import sys

NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 2
JOB_NUMBER = [1, 2]
thread_list = []

all_connections = []
all_addresses = []

ip = "localhost"
port = 6969
number_of_connections = 5

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((ip, port))
print("[Server] Server online...")
s.listen(number_of_connections)


def receive_msg(clientsocket):
    while True:
        msg = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        print(msg)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"[Server] New connection with {address}")
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=receive_msg, args=(clientsocket,))
    t2.daemon = True
    t2.start()


# MAIN CODE END
```